# Image doesn't appear in the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUI {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("logo.png");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(image);

        label.setText("Boom");
        frame.setTitle("SJ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(label);
    }  
}
```

I am beginner and just learning `JFrame`, can you guys tell me why isn't the image showing up? I have placed the Image (logo.png) in the folder where is that class.
I am using VSCode as IDE.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try to give the full path of the image?

Comment: ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("D:\Project\logo.png");
like this?

Comment: The image would need to be in the same folder as the generated jar file from your example

Comment: what jar?? sorry i am beginner can u explain elaborately?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp That's not actually true. The path is resolved against the current working directory, and that is not necessarily the location of the class, or the jar, or anything. Furthermore, if a jar was involved, the image should be included as a resource and read as a resource.

Comment: True sorry been a while since I've done swing.

Comment: @FSJ The documentation says to use forward slashes. `D:/Project/logo.png`.

Comment: Do you see the text of the label? `frame.add(label);` - Swing components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: @camickr good spot hopefully OP sees this in my example too

Comment: @camickr yah the label is visible

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource). Using the ImageIO.read(...) will generate an Exception if the image can't be found.

Comment: @camickr YO!!! Thanks a lot it worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Dusted off the old NetBeans and gave it a go...

You would want to do this:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("logo.png"))
```

Essentially the image is bundled in your jar file as a resource and in order to correctly extract it you need the  [Class#getResource(string name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)

Here is my full example with screenshot of my image placement:

[image]

**TestApp.java:**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestApp {

    public TestApp() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestApp();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img =  ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
   
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

If your logo is perhaps inside nested java package like this:

[image]

You would simply do:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/logo.png"))
```

**Update:**

As @camickr mentioned add all components to the `JFrame` before making it visible.

Also all Swing components should be created on the EDT via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` as also shown in my example.

Comment: Thanks!, but i am getting a error in getClass() as "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type ObjectJava(603979977)"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a Lot everyone whoever tried to help me!!

I used:

```
java.net.URL imageURL = app.class.getResource("download.png");
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
```

It worked!!
I referred it [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) !